# Spiral Step game thingy

Tags: identify-this-game

Probably the wrong forum, but how do you call these spirally things that you put on the top of a staircase and watch it fall down step by step?
Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Spiel-des-jahres?

Comment: Closing this question, it is asking about a toy, not a boardgame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they are commonly called a "[Slinky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slinky)".